# Verificar se carrinho NÃO está vazio Woocommerce 3.4+

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Pretendo verificar se o carrinho NÃO está vazio, mas não estou a conseguir!
Será que alguém me pode ajudar, por favor?

.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirecionar' );
    function redirecionar(){
        global $woocommerce;
        if ( !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
           // hello_world
        }
}
```

..

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
    function vazio() {
        if ( ! WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) { 
           // hello_world
        }
}
```

...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
    function vazio() {
        if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { 
           // hello_world
         }
}
```

O meu códgo:

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'vazio' );
    function vazio() {
        if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { ?>
        <div style="width: 20%;" class="footer-section <?php echo esc_html($woo);?>">
            <a href="<?php echo 'https://my_web_page.pt/finalizar-compra';?>" title="Finalizar Compra"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></a>
        </div>
    <?php   }
    } ?>
```

Comment: Utilize o método [**get_cart_contents_total**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#271-279). Já utilizou `var_dump( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() );` para checar o resultado?

Comment: @Valdeir obrigado, mas não estou a perceber!